# How to calculate delayed revenue in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to calculate revenue that is delayed by 4 months from the beginning of the year before receiving the full expected amount in month 5 and for the rest of the year.

[image: Expected & Actual Results]

In the attached picture you see that I expect 10,000 every month in 2021 with a 4 month ramp meaning in month 1 I will only receive 2,500 which is 10,000/4. In month 2 I will receive 5,000 which is 20,000/4 (10,000 from month 1 + 10,000 from month 2) and so on.

The problem is that the formula I use =SUM(OFFSET($G$14,0,0):G14)/$G$16 continues to sum and divide after month 5 and I would like it to stop at month 4.

I'd appreciate any help on tweaking my formula or recommending one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I played around with the formula and figured out a solution. Tweaking the formula to the below allowed me to resolve the delayed revenue in case it helps anyone else.

=SUM(OFFSET($G$14,0,IF(MONTH(G11)<=$G$16,$G$16-$G$16,MONTH(G11)-$G$16)):G14)/$G$16